# How to do housekeeping in jetty?

Tags: java, webserver, jetty

We let users upload some image files to our webserver. These files are of no use 10-15 mins after uploading. Is there any way to automatically delete these files e.g. all image files which have 'expire' in their name 15 mins after they were created?

Comment: why not use a cache and store the bytes of the image directly into the cache. Set an eviction/expire time on write (not access) of 10-15 minutes and the cache automatically takes care of the image. Any lookups for the image are answered directly from the cache (as long as the entry has not expired)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically setup quartz scheduler inside my webserver with a cron trigger

and the job looked more or like this

```
public static void deleteFilesOlderThanNdays(int daysBack, String dirWay, org.apache.commons.logging.Log log) {

    File directory = new File(dirWay);
    if(directory.exists()){

        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();            
        long purgeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (daysBack * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        for(File listFile : listFiles) {
            if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) {
                if(!listFile.delete()) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to delete file: " + listFile);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("Files were not deleted, directory " + dirWay + " does'nt exist!");
    }
}
```

ref:http://www.coderanch.com/t/384581/java/java/Delete-Files-Older-days

Answer (score 6):

You just answered your own question - get all files with word "expire" in the name and modified 15 minutes prior current time and delete them.

Here is code. It's not efficient but plain:

```
File dir=new File(".");
String []expiredFiles=dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.contains("expired")&& new File(dir,name).lastModified()<System.currentTimeMillis()-15*60*1000);                
    }
});
for(String file:expiredFiles){
    new File(dir,file).delete();
}
```

You can run it every 15 minutes or so. Or, more simple approach, run it when each request is answered and closed but thread is not stopped yet. For example when just after your close your output stream on the response object. It doesn't take much resources especially when thread is up and still running.

Comment: Actually you should run it like every minute :) Just create a `ServletContextListener` which will manage the lifecycle of `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule your clean-up job to run every minute.

Answer (score 2):

There no such thing in jetty, as mlapeyre says. Look at [Guavas cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Something like that will do the trick, i guess:

```
Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(DELETE_FILES_LISTENER)
       .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jetty has a built-in feature for that.
You could create a kind of GarbageCollector class and schedule the deletion of a file using a [ScheduledExecutorService:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
public class GarbageCollector {
    private ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void scheduleFileDeletion(Path path) {
        service.schedule(() -> {
            try {
                Files.delete(path);
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class to store information about uploading image like, `imagePath` and `uploadedTime`.

```
class UploadedImage {
    private Path imagePath;
    private long uploadedTime;
    public UploadedImage(Path imagePath, long uploadedTime) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.uploadedTime = uploadedTime;
    }
    public Path getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }
    public long getUploadedTime() {
        return uploadedTime;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final UploadedImage other = (UploadedImage) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.imagePath, other.imagePath)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.uploadedTime != other.uploadedTime) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Create a UploadedImage object for every image-uploading, and store them in a global ArrayList.

```
//...
ArrayList<UploadedImage> imageBucket = new ArrayList<>();
//...

public synchronized void uploadingImage(Path imagePath, long uploadedTime){         
     imageBucket.add(new UploadeImage(imagePath, uploadedTime));
}
```

And prepare a thread to perform the deletion of the files like following.

```
    boolean deletionOff = false;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private final long IMAGE_LIFE_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 15;//fifteen minutes
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!deletionOff) {
            //this fore-each will retrieve objects from OLDEST to NEWEST
            for (UploadedImage uploadedImage : imageBucket) {
                 //finds the elapsed time since the upload of this image
                long timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - uploadedImage.getUploadedTime();
                if (timeElapsed >= IMAGE_LIFE_TIME) {
                    //following commands will execute only if the image is eligible to delete
                    try {
                        Files.delete(uploadedImage.getImagePath());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        //
                    } finally {
                        imageBucket.remove(uploadedImage);
                    }
                } else {
                    //this block will execute when IMAGE_LIFE_TIME is
                    //bigger than the elapsed time which means the
                    //selected image only have 
                    //(IMAGE_LIFE_TIME - timeElapsed) of time to stay alive 
                    //NOTE :
                    //there is no need to check the next UploadedImage
                    //objects as they were added to the list after the
                    //currently considering UploadedImage object, 
                    //which is still has some time to stay alive                           
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(IMAGE_LIFE_TIME - timeElapsed);
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```